# How to drag and drop a row between two dataTables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, datatables

First Table :

```
$('#source').dataTable({
    "aaData": src,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
    "aoColumns": [
    {"mData": "Title"},
    {"mData": "ID"},
    {"mData": "Language"}
    ],
    });
```

Second table is initially empty:

```
$('#destination').dataTable({
    "aaData": dest,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
    "aoColumns": [
    {"mData": "Title"},
    {"mData": "ID"},
    {"mData": "Language"}
    ],
    });
```

Now I want to **DRAG and DROP** multiple rows (with a class "selected") from first table to second table.

On dragging and dropping, the rows with class "selected" should be deleted from #source table and added in #destination table.

If the drop is not in #destination, the row/rows should remain in #source table.

**NOTE 1**: I've been **able to achieve this on click** and need some help doing drag and drop.

**NOTE 2**: The sorting functionality of the two tables shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to get this working. You may have a look at the following Gist. It describes Drag&Drop between DataTables.

https://gist.github.com/davemo/706167

(@mod yes, i know - this is not a "good" answer, but all i got so far :P )

---

Addition:

This may prove helpful as well

[Dragging a row from one jquery Datatable and dropping it into another Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519187/dragging-a-row-from-one-jquery-datatable-and-dropping-it-into-another-datatable)

---

Solution:

Woohoo :D

I finally come across this forum post (please read entirely)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30197/add-remove-table-rows-on-drag-and-drop-between-two-datatables

Comment: Woops... just recognized this post is also from you XD